# Como descargar desde una url blob:https a un WebView

Tags: android, html, android-studio

Tengo mi app con un WebView e intento descargar un archivo .wav desde una url `blob:https//` pero me encuentro con el siguiente error `Can only download HTTP/HTTPS URIs: blob:https://`